# Android: Unable to share link as URL

Tags: android, android-intent, share, android-sharing

I am developing an application in which i want to share a custom link with the intent as:

```
Intent intentShare = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intentShare.setType("text/plain");
intentShare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "http://my_ip_address/abc/ayz/no/10");          
try {
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intentShare, "Select an action"));
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    // (handle error)
}
```

**Issue is:** I can share the link as a text to whats app etc. But it **share as text, not as link** on tap of which it opens in browser.

What i am missing, or what should i do to complete the task?
Please guide me.

Comment: you shared in facebook?

Comment: Not tried as the link is having my personal IP address

Comment: I don't understand your question. You are able to share it as a text, right? Now, you don't want to share it as a link? Is that what you are saying? What do you mean by 'don't want to share it as a link'?

Comment: You want to share it where whats app or anyother

Comment: @Yashasvi Link is shared as a text not as a link. And i want to share it as a link on which user can tap.

Comment: @Ajinkya I want to share link on all apps present in my device

Answer (score 1):

You can try two options :

1) As described here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/30926001/1594776

2) Use ACTION_VIEW intent, instead of ACTION_SEND.

Let me know if that works.